# How to register all Hosted Services with reflection in dotnet 5.0

Tags: c#, reflection, dependencies, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to register all my **worker services** as **Hosted service** in **dotnet 5.0** with **reflection**.

I've already registered all my project's application services in this way :

```
private static void RegisterApplicationServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        var applicationServices = (Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ConfigurationService)))
                              .GetTypes()
                              .Where(x => !x.IsInterface &&
                              x.GetInterface(typeof(IApplicationService).Name) != null);

        foreach (var serviceType in applicationServices)
        {
            var type = serviceType.UnderlyingSystemType;
            services.AddTransient(type.GetInterface($"I{type.Name}"), type);
        }

    }
```

But when it comes to **Hosted service** it doesn't work. I need some way to register all workers as Hosted services.

```
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService1>();
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService2>();
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService3>();
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService4>();
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService5>();
        services.AddHostedService<WokrerService6>();

private static void RegisterHostedServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        //What should I do here?
}
```

All the workers inherit from a **BaseWorker** class

```
   public abstract class BaseWorkerService<TWorkerService> :
         BackgroundService, IAppHostedService where TWorkerService : class
   {

   }
    public class TransactionSubscriberService :
                BaseWorkerService<TransactionSubscriberService>
   {

   }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I've got the same question, But haven't gotten any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

So, `AddHostedService` just adds singletons of type `IHostedService` and the *implementation type*. There is no magic here:

```
var types = someAssembly
   .GetTypes()
   // or however you want to target classes
   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IHostedService)));

foreach (var type in types)
  services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IHostedService), type));
```

However, the gotcha seemingly is that you can't block the `StartAsync`, otherwise the other services won't start:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.Run(() => DoSomething);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : I have never tried this, the code hasn't been tested, and it's a theoretical answer from the brief look at the source code*</sub>